# How to deal with the single quote in pl/sql code

Tags: oracle

I met below error when I execute the following code.
Error report:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 12
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

Can you please help me to find out the root reason.

```
declare
v_str varchar2(100):='XY';
v_cnt number := 1;
v_text varchar2(100);
v_sysdate date := sysdate;
begin
v_text := 'select to_char(' || '''' || v_sysdate || '''' || ',''yyyy/mm/dd'') from dual';
dbms_output.put_line(v_text);
execute immediate v_text into v_str;
dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
end;
```

Comment: Do you really need dynamic SQL in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to convert a char to a char as if the first one were a date. Notice that you're executing the following query:

```
select to_char('2014-03-14','yyyy/mm/dd') from dual
```

It doesn't make any sense. The "date" (2014-03-14) is actually a string and you can't treat that like if it were a date.

If you just want to cast v_sysdate to a varchar2, you could just do:

```
v_str := to_char(v_sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Or maybe you just were studying how dynamic SQL works...

Comment: V_SYSDATE is a date variable and when you're concatenating V_SYSDATE to the query string you are implicitly converting V_SYSDATE to a string. When the query is executed, what PL/SQL is actually executing is SELECT TO_CHAR('2014-03-14','YYYY/MM/DD') FROM DUAL, i.e, it is trying to convert V_SYSDATE to a string but it has been already converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please, everyone test it before answer... problem with execute immediate..

------ so i think this is what you wanted..

```
declare
v_str varchar2(100):='XY';

v_cnt number := 1;

v_text varchar2(100);
v_sysdate date := sysdate; --

begin

v_text := 'select to_char(:x,''yyyy.mm.dd'') from dual';--:x dynamically built sql statement using IN OUT v_variable1, IN v_variable2; 
dbms_output.put_line(v_text);

execute immediate v_text into v_str using in v_sysdate; 

dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
end;
```

you can't just put variable into execute string and expect something ;) you need to define him to use in that place... v_sysdate goes into defined :x place...